# Suggestions of hashtags while typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a website for my college event which is similar to the blogs. we will be writing the articles about the event and members can comment on it. So we want to allow the hashtag in the comment. These hashtags will only be the ones present in the table.

```
tbl_hashtag 
id - unique key not null
```

Now in the comment textarea when user clicks # and some character I want to suggest the hashtags which are present and allow only those.

How can I achieve this. I don't have much knowledge of js or jQuery but have very tight deadline.

I had tried this but dont know how to proceed with it:

```
$("#textdiv textarea").keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.charCode == 35)
    {
       ????
    }
});
```

Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: take a look at  http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/ or http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ or https://github.com/mataki/jquery-textarea-imput-support

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus you should really consider posting this as an answer, as the links to jquery-textcomplete really helped me as well! thanks, man!